# Invalid request provided: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule Validation exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I need to create just a TargetGroup and ListenerRule with the CloudFormation but i received error.

My CloudFormation:

```
TargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${StackName}-alb
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      Port: !Ref ContainerPort
      Protocol: HTTP
      Matcher:
        HttpCode: 200
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 10
      HealthCheckPath: !Ref HealthCheckPath
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
      HealthyThresholdCount: 2
      TargetType: ip
      TargetGroupAttributes:
        - Key: deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds
          Value: 30

  ListenerRule:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    DependsOn: 
      - TargetGroup
    Properties:
      Actions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
      Conditions:
        - Field: host-header
          Values:
            - "www.mydominian.*"
      ListenerArn: !Ref ListenerArn
      Priority: 164
```

[Invalid request provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKOVj.png)
So, the error is the image

Comment: What is your load balancer definition?

Comment: Hi Marcin, I need to create just one TargetGroup and ListenerRule, my load balancer I already have

Comment: I was to put a arn of listenerrule private, i passed the arn public of https and resolve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`AWS::StackName`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html#cfn-pseudo-param-stackname) looks like it's missing the `AWS::` prefix

---

Recommend trying the [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) in [VSCode](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cfn-lint-visual-studio-code) to see some of these errors inline while authoring templates along with autocompletion and documentation links:

[image: Visual Studio Code extension]

```sh
[cfn-lint] E1019: Parameter StackName for Fn::Sub not found at Resources/TargetGroup/Properties/Name/Fn::Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your recomendation but this not helped-me.

Comment: I was to put a arn of listenerrule private, i passed the arn public of https and resolve my problem

Answer (score 4):

It's just missing the `HostHeaderConfig` in the `Conditions` section.  Update it to the following:

```
Conditions:
  - Field: host-header
    HostHeaderConfig:
      Values:
        - "www.mydominian.*"
```

When you define `Field`, you'll need to use the correct `Config` section. Unfortunately, it's not smart enough to know which one to apply your pattern to.

For example, if you were using path-based routing it would look like this:

```
Conditions: 
  - Field: path-pattern
    PathPatternConfig:
      Values:
        - "/api/micro-service-1/*"
```

Comment: The OPs syntax isn't actually incorrect according to the documentation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticloadbalancingv2-listenerrule-rulecondition.html#cfn-elasticloadbalancingv2-listenerrule-rulecondition-values

`Values:`
If Field is host-header and you're not using HostHeaderConfig, you can specify a single host name (for example, my.example.com)...

Answer (score 4):

I would like to share that in my case the course of the problem was the number of conditions in the rule. I had them 6 instead of 5.

[Quotas for your Application Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-limits.html), where

**Rule**

- Match evaluations per rule: 5

Comment: GOD, you saved me. I wracked my brain so hard trying to figure out what was wrong with my configuration. Turns out it was this stupid limit.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

CloudFormation will also throw this "Invalid request provided" error if the permissions of the deploying user are incorrect.

We had to add an `elasticloadbalancing:CreateRule` `Action`, and supply the correct ARN conditions for the `listener` as well as a `listener-rule` wildcard in the `Resource` collection of the policy.

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "elasticloadbalancing:CreateRule"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:<region>:<account-id>:listener/app/<lb name>/<lb-id>/<listener-id>",
        "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:<region>:<account-id>:listener-rule/app/<lb name>/<lb-id>/<listener-id>/*"
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: The lack of CreateRule permission was exactly the issue. Much appreciated.

Comment: For us it was `DescribeRules` and `DescribeListeners`

Comment: Bless you. I don't know how you figured out such an obscure error message but this answer needs to be higher up,

Answer (score 1):

I also had this - and to add to other answers that talk about 'Condition values per rule' - that includes e.g. an HTTP Header check AND e.g. path checks.

So this was failing for me:

```
   0       Conditions:
   1         - Field: http-header
   2           HttpHeaderConfig:
   3             HttpHeaderName: Cookie
   4             Values:
   5               - '*MyCookieValue=*'
   6         - Field: path-pattern
   7           PathPatternConfig:
   8             Values:
   9               - '/path1'
  10               - '/path2'
  11               - '/path3'
  12               - '/path4'
  13               - '/path5'
```

...because the Cookie check counts as a value, as well as the 5 paths!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure "Condition Values per Rule" doesn't exceed [the quota](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-limits.html) of 5 rules per listener. The web console can help with that:

```
EC2
  -> Load Balancers
    -> [Select your load balancer]
      -> Listeners
        -> View/Edit Rules 
          -> Rule limits for condition values, wildcards, and total rules
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check *every character* of your values, the service validates them, but it seems like they have only this generic error message.

In my case, the problem was a redundant 's', I had

```
  Actions:
    - Type: forwards
```

Only after comparing character by character with an example, I noticed the redundant 's'.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the specified header value contained invalid characters:

```
Maximum 128 characters. Allowed characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9; spaces; the following special characters:
!"#$%&'()+,./:;<=>@[]^_`{|}~-; and wildcards (* and ?).
```